# MySQL left join, difference between null as value and no rows

Tags: mysql, left-join

Let's say I have two tables

TableA:

```
ID - Value1
===========
1  - A
2  - B
3  - C
4  - D
```

TableB:

```
ID - Value2
===========
1  - AA
3  - NULL
4  - DD
```

A normal join of these tables could be:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA TA
LEFT JOIN TableB TB ON TA.ID = TB.ID
```

Result would then be:

```
ID - Value1 - Value2
======================
1  - A - AA
2  - B - NULL
3  - C - NULL
4  - D - DD
```

How can I tell the difference between the NULL-value that symbolizes that no rows where matched (as for ID 2), and the NULL value that is joined as a value (ID 3)?

Comment: Well, what does NULL in table B represent? Why is there even a row for ID3 in that table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual return of the query will have 2 ID fields, one from TableA and other from TableB.  See these results and then you can see it's a simple matter of looking at the tb.id (id1):

```
id  value   id1 value1
 1    A      1    AA
 2    B
 3    C      3
 4    D      4    DD
```

Comment: Thanks! Simple enough and works fine! Why didn't i think of that?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the keys used in the `join`.  I'm not sure what you want to do, but:

```
SELECT TA.*, TB.*,
       (CASE WHEN TB.ID IS NULL THEN 'NO MATCH' ELSE 'MATCHED' END)
FROM TableA TA LEFT JOIN
     TableB TB
     ON TA.ID = TB.ID;
```

Comment: Hi, tried that, but theres no difference between where there is no match and where the value is null. Both cases shows "no match" in this example.

Comment: @gregoff - I just double checked Gordons solution and it works fine with the sample data you have given.

Comment: Hmm strange... Probably something i'm doing wrong then.

Comment: It is the same theory as the solution by Tom Joyal, but enables you to check in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `NULL` of the left join by using check `IS NULL` in `IF` or `CASE WHEN`. if `left join` `NULL` is coming you can check by `IF`  condition will give true.
**Note** : I assume in your tableB `NULL` is string

```
SELECT a.*, b.*,
IF(b.ID IS NULL, 'NO MATCH' , 'MATCHED')
FROM TableA a LEFT JOIN TableB b
ON a.ID = b.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TA.id, TA.Value1,TB.value2 FROM TableA 
       (CASE WHEN TB.ID IS NULL THEN 'NOT MATCH' ELSE 'MATCHED' END)
FROM TableA TA LEFT JOIN
     TableB TB
     ON TA.ID = TB.ID;
```